# How to set up attribute style using variables?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables:

`customBlock` witch is `<div class="column" used="true"></div>`

`customStyle` witch is `style="background: yellow"`

How can I assign the yellow background to the `customBlock`?
One option would be to get the 'yellow' word from the string and use
 `customBlock.setAttribute('background', yelloVariable)`

But I am looking (in javascript not jquery) for something clean like this: `customBlock.magic(customStyle)`

Comment: So you've got a string of invalid HTML and another string of HTML that is generally considered to be less than best practise and you want to join them together? Honestly, I'd back off and try to deal with the problem in a different way that didn't involve lumps of HTML in strings in the first place. Preferably using DOM.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

**1. If you want magic, this is at least a single line:**

```
customBlock.outerHTML = customBlock.outerHTML.split("<div").join("<div " + customStyle);
```

**2. Otherwise**

Iterate through the style statements (and I notice belatedly that I treated your `customStyle` as a style declaration, not as HTML here: that could be easily fixed)

```
// Break down by semi-colon separated statements
styleList = customStyle.split(";");

//Iterate through
for ( var i=0; i<styleList.length; i++ ) {

    //Break down statement into before and after colon
    var statement = styleList[i].split[":"];

    if ( ! statement[1] ) {
        //No colon: could just be empty statement or the empty string after the last semicolon
         continue;
    }
    //Trim whitespace from key
    var key = statement[0].split(" ").join("");
    //Set style
    customBlock.style[key] = statement[1];

}
```

EDIT: I just notices that your `customStyle` is HTML; I treated it here like a valid CSS string.

Comment: Already tried... I have also tried customBlock.attributes.style

Comment: This is a way of doing it, but I was wondering if there is that 'magic' way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var customBlock = "<div id='cB' class='column' used='true'></div>"; //A STRING. NOTE: I GAVE THE DIV AN ID
    var customStyle = "background-color: yellow; width:50px; height:50px"; //I GAVE IT DIMENSIONS SO YOU CAN SEE IT

    var attachColumn = document.body.innerHTML+=customBlock;//ADD CUSTOMBLOCK TO SOMETHING IN THE DOCUMENT - eg. THE BODY
    document.getElementById("cB").style=customStyle; //REFERENCING THE ID OF THE ELEMENT THAT IS NOW IN THE DOM, WE ADD THE STYLE ATTRIBUTE
```

```html
<body></body>
```